# How to get up-to-date search results when searching for javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

Recently I've observed a lot of people still giving links to javadocs of 1.4.2. This is not quite a good practice and I'd like to raise the question.

This happens because search engines (Google at least) give the old javadoc if one searches for, let's say, `java.lang.String`

So, how to get the javadoc for the correct (currently 1.6) version of JDK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In almost all cases, adding the version after the searched class gets the desired result on top. For example:

- "java.lang.String 6"
- "java.util.Collection 5"

(note - it's not "1.6" - only "6")

Answer (score 1):

As they are updated, the tutorials are already referencing draft version of the Java 7 API. For example [*How to Use Tables*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) refers to [`JTable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to download and install the javadoc when I'm installing a new Java version.
So I always have the correct javadoc on the disk.  Uses some disk space but it's faster and allows working offline.

<sup>Drawback: you can not copy&paste the links in a forum</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I've always been surprised that nobody at Google updates documentation searches to default to the latest versions.

I usually just add "Java 6" if I am searching for "Java 6" and "Galileo" if I am searching for Eclipse stuff (as I usually get the Eclipse 3.2 docs with a default search). Adding JavaDoc for good measure helps with the more obscure classes in general.