# How to google for spring 3.0 documentation?

Tags: spring

When giving links to spring docs it would be best to link the 3.0 ones, but googling isn't quite productive with them (yet). Is there some "shortcut" (like [for java core classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302042/how-to-get-up-to-date-search-results-when-searching-for-javadoc))? For example:

"spring factory-method 2.5.6" gives the docs about 2.5.6, but "spring factory-method 3.0" doesn't give anything from 3.0.

If you know the name of the chapter (after seeing it in the 2.5.6 results), you can add it to the search terms, like "spring factory-method 3.0 IoC Container" it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`spring factory-method 3.0.x`](http://www.google.com/search?q=spring+factory-method+3.0.x) results in a link to the newest reference documentation. Is it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

For javadoc, if the first result is for 2.5.6 / 2.0.x, you can open it and change the URL from:

```
/2.0.x/api/...
```

to

```
/3.0.x/javadoc-api/...
```

For example try:

> http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html
>
> http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html